# Structure in ctype

Tags: python, c, struct, structure, ctypes

I am new to ctypes. I have written a function using structure in c. I want to call it in python using ctypes. If I compile and run in linux there is no error.
But if I do it using python it throws error.

C-program

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct add1{
        int a;
        int b;
};

int main(){
        int c;
        struct add1 s;
        printf("Enter 2 no :\n");
        scanf("%d%d",&s.a,&s.b);
        c = s.a + s.b;
        printf("C is : %d",c);
        return c;
}
```

```
obj = CDLL("./add12add1.so",mode=1)
print(obj)
#print(obj.add1)


class s(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("a",c_int),("b",c_int)]

c = s(8,9)
#print(c.add1)
print(c.a)
print(c.b)
print(c.a+c.b)
print(c.add1)
```

AttributeError: 's' object has no attribute 'add1'

How to solve this error?

Comment: Please post the full traceback so we see the failing line.

Comment: Also, post something runnable. That means importing ctypes and not doing `obj = CDLL("./add12add1.so",mode=1)`. The problem can be reproduced without the import so no need for that extra complication in the example.

Answer (score 0):

You have a structure that you named "add1" in the C code, but named it "s" in the python code. They both have fields called "a" and "b", but neither has a field called "add1". You can use different names for structures and fields in the two programs, they just need to align the data the same. Usually, though, one would try to keep the same names to avoid confusion. And I think that's what happened here. The python code that matches the C code is

```
class add1(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("a",c_int),("b",c_int)]

s = add1(8,9)
print(s.a)
print(s.b)
print(s.a+s.b)
```

`s.add1` doesn't exist in the python or the C code because `add1` is not a member of either structure.